# Open a file in binary what kind of stream it?

Tags: c++, iostream

Is this piece of code meant to open a file that contains binary data? Or open a file of character data and turn it into binary data within the input stream?

```
 void open_infile(ifstream& ifs)
{
    string infile;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> infile;

   ifs.open(infile.c_str(),ios_base::binary);
    if (!ifs) error("can't open out file");
}
```

Comment: What does "turn character data into binary" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter: don't you know, text is always stored as 1's and 0's ;)

Answer (score 2):

For `ifs.open(infile.c_str(),ios_base::binary);`, it's meant to open a file that contains binary data.

Check out [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/) for more info.